# Aggregate group by array and divide quantity to array length

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, group-by, aggregation

Now I want to aggregate schema to group by users in array and divide items field to array length to create average.. 
This is simple json data ->

```
[{"users": ["5ea40086fc4b145b489da93d","5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"],"isBuilt": true, "_id": "5eadd43b30f97f342cf663fc", "items": 3, ...},
{"users": ["5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"], "isBuilt": true, "_id": "5ead419081eec52258b67f70", "items": 5, ...}]
```

And after aggregating with ->

```
Building.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        updatedAt: {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lte: endDate
        },
        isBuilt: true
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$users"
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$users",
        items: {
          $sum: '$items'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        user: '$_id',
        items: 1,
        _id: 0
      }
    }
  ])
```

I got this json ->

```
[{"items": 3, "user": "5ea40086fc4b145b489da93d"}, {"items": 8, "user": "5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"}]
```

As you see here I got **sum of items**. In initial data `Users "5ea40086fc4b145b489da93d" and "5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"` have 3 items, and `user "5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"` has 5 items. And after aggregating they count by sum of items, that `user "5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405" -> 8 items, and user "5ea40086fc4b145b489da93d" -> 3 items`... Now I want make average items to users, like if length of array users is 2 or more it will divide items and give sum.. **and final json will look like** ->

```
[{"items": 1.5, "user": "5ea40086fc4b145b489da93d"}, {"items": 6.5, "user": "5e8cb9a4462e45178c4d3405"}]
```

PS if result of item is not integer, result should be rounded to ten

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with aggregation ->

```
Building.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        updatedAt: {
          $gte: startDate,
          $lte: endDate
        },
        isBuilt: true
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        itemsAvg: {
          $divide: ["$items", {$size: "$users"}]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        roundedItemsAvg: {
          $round: ["$itemsAvg", 1]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$users"
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$users",
        items: {
          $sum: '$roundedItemsAvg'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        user: '$_id',
        items: 1,
        _id: 0
      }
    }
  ])
```